# Do exposed filters work in Views 7.x-3.3?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

When I create a filter, check the expose filter box, click save, then open the filter up again the exposed filter checkbox is uncheked...

I noticed when clicking save the filter is called: "Content: Assessment (or Unknown) | Settings" instead of "Content: Assessment (exposed) | Settings"

Anybody know what's going on here? I've tried creating an entirely new view and the same thing happens.

---

The field I am exposing is a simple taxonomy list.

I created a short video showing the issue:
http://www2.intensiveintervention.org/views_issue/

---

I found a thread on a seemingly related issue: http://drupal.org/node/1343482 but this did not solve my problem.

---

Downgrading views to 7.x-3.1 did not have any effect.

Comment: The short answer is yes, exposed filters work in Views 3.3.  Views is the most popular Drupal module and it would not have a major release where one of its major features, Exposed Filters, did not work.  What kind of field are you trying to expose?  How is that field configured?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of cTools installed?

Comment: I'm running the latest recommended: 7.x-1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem.

There is, as of today, incompatibility between Views and Theme Developer. If I disable Theme Developer views acts normally.

FYI for everybody else having this problem!